# concepts extraction from stanford parsing tree nlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am nlp research beginner
I want to extract the concepts from text
for example "The Thing Things albums" the concept is "The Thing Things"

I am using parsing tree for noun phrases **but** in this example the tree extracts "The Thing Things" &"albums"
and another example 
"Who started the handset alliance?" I expected that "handset alliance" but the noun phrase is"the handset alliance"

how can I solve them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of "concepts" is not perfectly clear to me, but take Illinois Shallow Parser might be useful for this. See a demo here: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/shallowparse/?id=7